# Styling CSS consecutively

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario:

This HTML is dynamically generated and continually growing.

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message person-1">
    <div class="message person-1">
    <div class="message person-2">
    <div class="message person-2">
    <div class="message person-2">
    <div class="message person-1">
    ...
</div>
```

Applying normal styling I get this:

[image: Chat styling]

However, I wish to group consecutive messages by the same person. This would mean, for each consecutive group, removing the margin between consecutive classes when they're not the first or last-child and also altering the first and last child's border radii.

I have looked into this: http://www.sitepoint.com/contiguous-sibling-selector/ but not sure how to get that to work for a list of indeterminate length.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: can you post your css for this section?

Comment: I think it may be possible, but you may have to generate your html differently.  Instead of class names like "message person-1" (to whatever number), just use two alternating classes, such as "message person" and "message person-alt".  Then you write sibling selector css based on just those 2 classes.  Haven't tested it, but it might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without changing the HTML, we can use the `+` selector to select continuous messages from the same person. We can then overlap the border-radius to hide it:

```
.person-1 + .person-1,
.person-2 + .person-2 {
  margin: -10px 5px 0;
}
```

[image: messages example]

### Complete Example

```css
#messages {
  width: 200px;
}
.message {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 5px 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.person-1 {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
.person-2 {
  background: purple;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
.person-1 + .person-1,
.person-2 + .person-2 {
  margin: -10px 5px 0;
}
img {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message person-1">Hello How are you?</div>
  <div class="message person-2">Good thanks</div>
  <div class="message person-2">and you?</div>
  <div class="message person-2">:)</div>
  <div class="message person-1">I'm so great!</div>
  <div class="message person-2">Awesome</div>
  <div class="message person-1">Yeah!</div>
  <div class="message person-2">Plz Respond</div>
  <div class="message person-2">Plz Respond</div>
  <div class="message person-2">Plz Respond
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="message person-2">Plz Respond</div>
  <div class="message person-1">Yeah!</div>
  <div class="message person-1">hi!</div>
  <div class="message person-1">hi!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to eliminate the margin (if you only use a `margin-top` to create margin between those elements), and the `border-radius` for *all* elements following on of the same type, like this:

```css
.message { clear:both; margin-top:.5em; padding:.5em; width:5em; border-radius:.5em; }
.person-1 { float:left; background:green; }
.person-2 { float:right; background:blue; }
.person-1 + .person-1, .person-2 + .person-2 { margin-top:0; border-radius:0; }
.person-1:first-child, .person2 + .person-1,
.person-2:first-child, .person-1 + .person-2 { border-radius:.5em .5em 0 0; }
```

```html
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message person-1">foo</div>
    <div class="message person-1">bar</div>
    <div class="message person-1">baz</div>
    <div class="message person-2">abc</div>
    <div class="message person-2">def</div>
    <div class="message person-1">ghi</div>
</div>
```

However, this will leave the last element of a “group” with no border-radius at the bottom as well; and that can not be fixed easily, because you can not select an element by what comes *after* it, only by what comes *before* it – so keeping the border-radius in place for the last element before the group changes, is not possible I think.

Now, if you only want to work with solid background colors and no opacity/alpha channel, and have enough padding on each element, as your screenshot suggests – then you could simply leave the border-radius for all elements in place, and “eliminate” it by dragging the elements over each other a bit by a negative margin, like so:

```css
.message { clear:both; margin-top:.5em; padding:.5em; border-radius:.5em; width:5em; }
.person-1 { float:left; background:green; }
.person-2 { float:right; background:blue; }
.person-1 + .person-1, .person-2 + .person-2 { margin-top:-.75em; }
```

```html
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message person-1">foo</div>
    <div class="message person-1">bar</div>
    <div class="message person-1">baz</div>
    <div class="message person-2">abc</div>
    <div class="message person-2">def</div>
    <div class="message person-1">ghi</div>
</div>
```

Whether that will work for you, will depend on the details of how exactly you want it to look like – what specific margins, paddings and border-radius you want to use.

If you want “more” than that, then you might have to change the HTML structure. Using a grouping element around the messages by the same person should not be that hard either – you just have to check when appending a new message, whether the person sending it is the same that send the last message or not, and depending on that either append the message to the existing last grouping element, or create a new grouping element for the other person first.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working like this... not sure if this will suit your style

```css
.message{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:0;
}

.person-1, .person-1:first-of-type{
  background-color: green;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 5px;

}

.person-1 + .person-1,
.person-2 + .person-2{
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.person-1 + .person-2,
.person-2 + .person-1{
  margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.person-2, .person-2:first-of-type{
  background-color: blue;
  text-align:right;
  display:block;
  float:right;
  margin: 0 5px;
    width: 60%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message person-1">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-1">how ru</div>
    <div class="message person-2">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-2">well, you?</div>
    <div class="message person-2">long time no see</div>
    <div class="message person-1">I know</div>
  <div class="message person-1">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-1">how ru</div>
    <div class="message person-2">hi</div>
  <div class="message person-1">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-1">how ru</div>
    <div class="message person-2">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-2">well, you?</div>
    <div class="message person-2">long time no see</div>
    <div class="message person-1">I know</div>
  <div class="message person-1">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-1">how ru</div>
    <div class="message person-2">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-2">well, you?</div>
    <div class="message person-2">long time no see</div>
  <div class="message person-2">hi</div>
    <div class="message person-2">well, you?</div>
    <div class="message person-2">long time no see</div>
    <div class="message person-1">I know</div>  
  <div class="message person-2">well, you?</div>
    <div class="message person-2">long time no see</div>
    <div class="message person-1">I know</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you dynamically creating the HTML? Using JS I would suggest tracking who sent the last message. Then if the next message is from the same source as the last (same person sent it) it could be grouped. That way instead of

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="message person-1">
        <div id="msg1"...
        <div id="ms2"...
    </div>
    <div class="message person-2">
        <div id="msg3"...
        <div id="ms4"...
    </div>
    <div class="message person-1">
        <div id="msg5"...
    ...
</div>
```

How do you feel about Frameworks? [Angular's ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) would be good for this.